# How to make the html table responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html-table

I have used Bootstrap div to make the below table,but its not responsive for mobile devices.
I have used col-xs,but still the column merge with each other in  mobile view.Is there any other way to make this code responsive to mobile devices?

```
<div class="container" style="color: grey; padding-top: 40px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-12" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;">

                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-4">
                    <span>Item</span>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                    <span>Price</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                    <span>Quantity</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                    <span>Total</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                    <span>Delivery Charge</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                    <span>Discount</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                    <span>Subtotal</span>
                </div>
            </div>


         </div>

</div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5">
                <img src="https://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/i/0/large/Mboss-Overnighters-SDL963993531-1-2f227.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7 ">
                <h5>Deisy brown Laptop Overnight</h5><br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-2 ">
                        <h5>
                            <b>Seller Information:</b>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-10">
                        <h6>
                            <b>Book Centre</b><br>

                            371 Colvinjh de sihjglva ,<br>
                            vvv Place,<br>
                            Chghhhgg2<br>
                            0123689955<br>
                        </h6>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

             <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
            <span>5780</span><br>
        </div>
             <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
            <span>  5780</span>
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
            <span> 5780</span>
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
            <span>0%</span>
        </div>
             <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
            <span>575855</span>
        </div>
           <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
            <span>575855</span>
        </div>
       </div>


    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Use table-responsive feature of bootstrap. read more [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive)

Comment: Use footable https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/index.html that is the best way make table responsive

Comment: Where is the table in your code ? also if you are using `col-xs-1` and `col-md-1` too how do you expect it to show a different layout in extra small screens ?

Comment: You're missing quite a few "row" divs

Comment: either you can do it like https://codepen.io/geoffyuen/pen/FCBEg this or using bootstrap please add the class "table-responsive" like here https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_table-responsive&stacked=h

Answer (score 8):

The following four options can be considered to make a table responsive. Please choose the one that fits your requirement.

**Squash**: If columns have little content they might squash horizontally with no issues on a mobile screen so not changing the layout needs to be a valid option.

**Vertical scroll**: If the layout and content is exact and critical, a user could scroll to the left or right. This is trivial in CSS with an overflow="auto" wrapper.

**Collapse by rows**: Split each row into its own single column mini-table on small screens. Switching display:table into display:block will cause this with normal table markup.

**Collapse by columns**: This is where things get tricky. You can't do this with normal table markup in pure CSS because the code order is by rows and the  wrappers lock it in. We either have to change the markup or start manipulating with JavaScript.
[image]

Comment: For Collapse by Row:
`@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .table tr td {
    display: block;
  }
}`

Answer (score 3):

You can just wrap your `<table>` tag inside of `<div class="table-responsive"></div>` since you're using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). Just like this: (use `<table>` instead of grid system (e.g. col-xs-1 etc.))

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Visit this link (bootstrap) for more info:
[[Visit Me](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive)]

.. That's it! 
Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help in making a table responsive.

> Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4m4ex229/)
>   **HTML :**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>Gender</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Qasim</td>
            <td>23yrs</td>
            <td>Male</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ali</td>
            <td>19yrs</td>
            <td>Male</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>William</td>
            <td>34yrs</td>
            <td>Male</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS :**

```
td{
  width:100px;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    thead {
        display: none;
    }
    tr{
      display:grid;
      border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
    }
    td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Name"; }
    td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Age"; }
    td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Gender"; }

    td:before{
      width:150px;
      float:left;
    }
    td{
      width:300px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is better if you use Bootstrap responsive table. Here is the link. this is most preferable link. i used many times.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_table-responsive&stacked=h

Answer (score 0):

@temp Long time back i used following code to make my table responsive. I hope it will help you.

```css
/*...............Table Starts....................*/
.table_custom_1 {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.table_custom_1 td {
    display: block;
}

.table_custom_1 th, .table_custom_1 td {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
}

.table_custom_1, .custom_table {
    width: 100%;
}

.table_custom_1 thead tr th, .custom_table tr th {
    background: #ECECEC none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #999999;
    font-family: opensans-Bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 5px 6px;
}

.table_custom_1 tbody tr td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    color: #414042;
    font-family: opensans-regular;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 6px;
    vertical-align: top;
    word-break: break-all;
}

.table_custom_1 tbody tr td.table_secondary_text {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #999999;
}

.table_custom_1 tr td:first-child {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.table_custom_1 tr td:last-child, .table_custom_1 tr th:last-child {
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.table_custom_1 tr.selected td {
    background: #FAFAFA;
}

.table_custom_1 .btn {
    display: inline-block;
}

.table_custom_1 .table_icon i {
    color: #878787;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
}

.table_custom_1 .table_icon:hover, .table_custom_1 .table_icon .table_icon:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.table_custom_1 .badge {
    margin-top: -3px;
    margin-left: 4px;
}

.table_custom_1 thead tr th input {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.table_custom_1 .table_custom_1 {
    border: medium none;
}

.table_custom_1 tbody tr td i.indicator {
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 8px;
}

/*.....................Media Queries starts.........*/
@media (max-width: 700px) {

.table_custom_1 th, .table_custom_1 td {
    display: inherit;
}

.table_custom_1 td:before {
    content: attr(data-th) ": ";
    width: 6.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #b7b7b7;
}

.table_custom_1 {
    border: 0px;
}

.table_custom_1 tr {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px -3px rgb(164, 164, 164);
}

.table_custom_1 tr td {
    padding: 4px 10px !important;
}

.table_custom_1 tbody tr td:first-child:before {
    padding-left: 0;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
}

.table_custom_1 tbody tr td:first-child {
    font-family: OpenSans-Semibold;
    color: #217589;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.table_custom_1.checkbox_table thead tr th:first-child {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.table_custom_1.checkbox_table thead tr th, .table_custom_1 thead {
    display: none;
}

.checkbox_table thead {
    display: block !important;
}
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
.table_custom_1 tr, .table_custom_1 td {
    display: block;
}

.table_custom_1 tbody tr td:first-child {
    color: #217589;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.table_custom_1 thead {
    display: none;
}


}

@media (min-width: 480px) {

.table_custom_1 td:before {
    display: none;
}

.table_custom_1 th:first-child, .table_custom_1 td:first-child {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.table_custom_1 th:last-child, .table_custom_1 td:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row">
                     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                     <table class="table_custom_1">
                           <thead>
                              <tr>
                                 <th>Name</th>
                                 <th>Age</th>
                                 <th>D.O.B</th>
                                 <th>Location</th>
                              </tr>
                           </thead>
                           <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                 <td>Rahul</td>
                                 <td data-th="Age">20</td>
                                 <td data-th="D.O.B">1977</td>
                                 <td data-th="Location">Delhi</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td data-th="Name">Vivek</td>
                                 <td data-th="Age">30</td>
                                 <td data-th="D.O.B">1986</td>
                                 <td data-th="Location">Vadodara</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td data-th="Name">Sahil</td>
                                 <td data-th="Age">23</td>
                                 <td data-th="D.O.B">1973</td>
                                 <td data-th="Location">J&K</td>
                              </tr>
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                       
                     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my example:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=s, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/responsive-table.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>Responsive Tables</title>

</head>

<body style="background:#F2F2F2">

        <!-- This is populated dynamically with JQuery since Pseudo elements can't be set in JS-->
        <div id="custom-css"></div>
        <!-- DONT DELETE THIS DIV -->

        <div class="table-container">

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>TEAM NAME</th>
                    <th>WINS</th>
                    <th>LOSSES</th>
                    <th>GOALS FOR</th>
                    <th>GOALS DIFFERENCE</th>
                    <th>POINTS</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Team A</td>
                    <td>26</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>77</td>
                    <td>+57</td>
                    <td>85</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Team B</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>86</td>
                    <td>+64</td>
                    <td>83</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Team C</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>+30</td>
                    <td>67</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Team D</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>+26</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div><!-- close table container -->

        <div class="table-container" style="margin-top:5em">

            <table>
                <tr>
                  <th>CLUB</th>
                  <th>MANAGER</th>
                  <th>COUNTRY</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Liverpool</td>
                  <td>Jurgen Klopp</td>
                  <td>England</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Real Madrid</td>
                  <td>Zinedine Zidane</td>
                  <td>Spain</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Celtic FC</td>
                  <td>Neil Lennon</td>
                  <td>Scotland</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tottenham</td>
                  <td>Jose Mourinho</td>
                  <td>England</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Atlético Madrid</td>
                  <td>Diego Simeone</td>
                  <td>Spain</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Inter Milan</td>
                  <td>Antonio Conte</td>
                  <td>Italy</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div><!-- close table container -->

</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/responsive-table.js"></script>

</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap");

.table-container {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 2% 1.5%;
  padding: 1%;
  color: #555555;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400; 
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%; 
}

/* Table Header Cell and Standard Cell */
th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px; 
}

/* Table Headings */
th {
  color: #555555;
  background: #DDD;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600; 
}


/* For All Devices Above 600px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {

  /* Styles the background color off every odd table row */
  tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #F2F2F2 ;
  }

}
/* Close Media Query */


/* For All Devices Below 600px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  .container {
    margin: 3.5% 1.5%; 
  }

  /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
  table,
  thead,
  tbody,
  th,
  td,
  tr {
    display: block; 
  }

  /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
  thead tr {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px; 
  }

  /* Add Border to make easier to read*/
  tr {
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  }

  /* Behave  like a "row" */
  td {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 60%; 
  }

  td:nth-child(1) {
    background: #DDD; 
  }

  /* Now like a table header */
  td:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    font-weight: 600;
  }

  /* Hide Table Headings */
  th {
    display: none; 
  }

}
```

Javascript / Jquery

```
function responsiveTable(screenSize) {

     // If media query is below 600px
    if (screenSize.matches) {

        // Array to push up CSS styles too
        var stylesArray = [];

        // Getting the amount of tables
        var tableCount = $('table').length;

        // Iterate through each table
        for(a = 1; a <= tableCount; a++) {

            // Target each indivdual table
            var tableClass  = ".table-container:nth-of-type("+(a+1)+") table";

            // Declaring unique table class
            var newTableClass = "table-"+(a);

            // Add Unique Class to each table occurence
            $(tableClass).addClass(newTableClass);

            // Getting Table Headings for Indivdual Classes
            var tableClassHeading = "."+newTableClass +  " th";

             // Count the table headings
            var tableHeadingCount = $(tableClassHeading).length;

            // Iterate through Table Headings
            for(i = 0; i < tableHeadingCount; i++) {

                // Adding the . notation to make it a class to use with JQuery
                var editedClass = "."+newTableClass;

                // Getting the value of the table heading
                var tableHeading = $(editedClass).find("th").eq(i).html();

                // Creating CSS Style and Setting Table Row (Heading) with Table Heading;
                var cssRole = editedClass+' td:nth-of-type('+(i+1)+'):before {content: "'+tableHeading+'"}';

                // Pushing CSS style to Styles Array
                stylesArray.push(cssRole);

            }// close the i for loop


        } //close the a for loop


        // Building the CSS stylesheet
        var styleSheet = "<style> ";

        // Iterate through each style rule
        for(q = 0; q < stylesArray.length; q++) {

            // Setting the CSS Rule
            var indivdualStyleRule = stylesArray[q];

            // Appending the rule to string
            styleSheet += indivdualStyleRule;
        }

        // Finished CSS Style
        var finishedStyleSheet = styleSheet + " </style>";

        // Add Style to HTML
        $('#custom-css').append(finishedStyleSheet);


    }// close if for media query

    else {

        // Clear all styles that were created
        $('#custom-css').empty();

    }// close else

}// close responiveTable function


// Set the responsive width for tables. Must match value set in css
var smallScreenSize = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)");

// Call listener responsiveTable function at run time
responsiveTable(smallScreenSize); 

// Attach listener function on state changes
smallScreenSize.addListener(responsiveTable);
```

My Code: [Preview](https://garathd.github.io/responsive-tables/)

Github: [Code](https://github.com/Garathd/responsive-tables/)